# Tensorflow simple cumulative sum of product RNN cell

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, cumulative-sum

I am trying to build a Tensorflow model that calculates a cumulative sum of products of two of the input features, i.e. predicting on only (1,2) should return 2, and then predicting on (2,2) should give 6=(1 * 2) + (2 * 2)

```py
model.predict([1,2])
>>> 2

model.predict([2,2])
>>> 6

model.reset_states()
model.predict([2,2])
>>> 4
```

I have tried the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


class MinimalRNNCell(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.states = np.array([0])
        self.state = np.array([0])
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        output = tf.math.add(prev_output,inputs)
        
        return output, [output]
    

# Define model
#input
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
#split input
x1,x2 = tf.split(inp, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
#calculate product
product = tf.math.multiply(x1,x2)
#reshape product
time_product = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,1))(product)
#Define memory cell and layer
memory_product = MinimalRNNCell(units=1)
layer_product = tf.keras.layers.RNN(memory_product)
#calculate cumulative product
cumulative_product = layer_product(time_product)

output = cumulative_product

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, output)


if __name__=="__main__":
    x = np.array([
        [1, 2],
        [2, 2]
    ])

    model.compile()
    y = model.predict(x)
    print()
    print("outptut: ", y)
>>> [[2],
     [4]]
```

Note the reason i split inputs is because this is the minimal model that should work. The model i am implementing is more complex and has more steps interlinked but it is the accumulation i can't get to work.
I feel like something like a cumulative sum is easily implemented using **RNN** or **LSTM** cells, but it does not work how I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to accumulate the product then `initialize` the `weight` on `build()` method then add each time the result of `model.predict()` to it. Here is the code...

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
class CumulativeProduct(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CumulativeProduct, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.cumulative_product = self.add_weight(shape=(), initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.cumulative_product.assign(self.cumulative_product + tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_prod(inputs, axis=1)))
        return self.cumulative_product
    
    def reset_states(self):
        self.cumulative_product.assign(0.)

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
cumulative_product = CumulativeProduct()
cum_prod = cumulative_product(inp)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, cum_prod)
x = [[1, 2], [2,2]]
model.predict(x)
```

```
6.0
```

```
x = [[2, 2]]
model.predict(x)
```

```
10.0
```

```
#to reset the model variable
cumulative_product.reset_states()
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not quite there. While it gives the correct values for individual predictions it does not when  doing multiple eg:

```
model.predict([[1,2],[2,2]])
>>> 8
```
while the result should still be 6

Comment: The code has been updated...